# How to Update row using realm database in android?

Tags: android

Here is my code

```
if (userDetailRealmModel.getuID() != i) {
      userDetailRealmModel.setUser_id(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUser_id());
      userDetailRealmModel.setFirstname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getFirstname());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLastname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLastname());
      userDetailRealmModel.setEmail(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getEmail());
      userDetailRealmModel.setPhone_no(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getPhone_no());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLatitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLatitude());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLongitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLongitude());
      userDetailRealmModel.setIs_private(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getIs_private());
      userDetailRealmModel.setCreation_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getCreation_datetime());
      userDetailRealmModel.setUpdate_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUpdate_datetime());

      realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDetailRealmModel);
      //userDetailRealmModelArray.add(userDetailRealmModel);  
    }
```

I want to update my database but it didn't work properly

Comment: I think you are not commiting.. Try 
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDetailRealmModel);
realm.commitTransaction()

Comment: Getting this Error :

 User-space exception detected!
                                                                                 io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0
                                                                                     at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:636)

Comment: @AnkitaRamoliya which is your primary key?

Comment: userDetailRealmModel.getuID() is my Primary key

Answer (score 0):

If you have `userDetailModelArrayList` containing list of `RealmObjects` you can simply update database using

```
    if (userDetailRealmModel.getuID() != i){
       realm.beginTransaction();
       realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i));
       realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

It will update your realm Database row using primary key of object.

if it doesn't have realm objects in list, You have to manually update it as below:

```
   if (userDetailRealmModel.getuID() != i) {
          realm.beginTransaction();
          userDetailRealmModel.setUser_id(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUser_id());
          userDetailRealmModel.setFirstname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getFirstname());
          userDetailRealmModel.setLastname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLastname());
          userDetailRealmModel.setEmail(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getEmail());
          userDetailRealmModel.setPhone_no(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getPhone_no());
          userDetailRealmModel.setLatitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLatitude());
          userDetailRealmModel.setLongitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLongitude());
          userDetailRealmModel.setIs_private(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getIs_private());
          userDetailRealmModel.setCreation_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getCreation_datetime());
          userDetailRealmModel.setUpdate_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUpdate_datetime());
          realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDetailRealmModel);
          realm.commitTransaction(); 
        }
```

Comment: which error? can you update your question according to that?

Comment: Still getting these Error : 

User-space exception detected!                                                                             io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0 
at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:636) 
at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRow(Table.java:365)
at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:661)
at Activity.FindContacts.insertContactData(FindContacts.java:848) 
at Activity.FindContacts.access$400(FindContacts.java:81)
at Activity.FindContacts$8.onSuccess(FindContacts.java:743

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (userDetailRealmModel.getuID() != i) {
      userDetailRealmModel.setUser_id(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUser_id());
      userDetailRealmModel.setFirstname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getFirstname());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLastname(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLastname());
      userDetailRealmModel.setEmail(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getEmail());
      userDetailRealmModel.setPhone_no(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getPhone_no());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLatitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLatitude());
      userDetailRealmModel.setLongitude(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getLongitude());
      userDetailRealmModel.setIs_private(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getIs_private());
      userDetailRealmModel.setCreation_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getCreation_datetime());
      userDetailRealmModel.setUpdate_datetime(userDetailModelArrayList.get(i).getUpdate_datetime());

      realm.beginTransaction();
           realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDetailRealmModel); //pass your object
           realm.commitTransaction(); 
    }
```

#### Update

Please uninstall your application, then again clean build-> rebuild and install.

check [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3099)

Comment: Update

The error says that you are entering the same value for the primary key.

For that i'm askning

Comment: I have updated my answer check it again @AnkitaRamoliya

Comment: @AnkitaRamoliya let me know the result

Comment: @AnkitaRamoliya Didi You tried clean build after unsinstalling?